# How to mount/unmount devices?

Tags: shell, files, directories

I'm interested in mounting/umounting usb and other devices directly from emacs.

In many file managers (like nautilus) the devices are automatically discovered and indicated with an icon, it's possible to do something smart for emacs (maybe in `dired`)?

Comment: I'm on linux, so I could do some calls to `mount` and `umount`

Comment: For sudo I have ```(defun sudo-shell-command (command)
    "Execute a shell-command with sudo tramp."
    (shell-command (concat
        "echo "
        (read-passwd (concat "[sudo] password for " user-login-name ": "))
        " | sudo -S "
        command)))```

Comment: One should not mount plugable devices as superuser. There are packages for mounting plugable devices from user space: http://storaged.org/doc/udisks2-api/latest/udisksctl.1.html There also automounters for Linux: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs

Comment: See also https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=usbmount

Comment: So what I want is a way to comfortably access and eject devices directly from emacs.

Comment: In my opinion you could simple use autofs, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autofs